# How can I remove the kses filters when saving a specific post type ? (it breaks my JSON)

Tags: filters, save-post, wp-kses

I want to store JSON in my post_content, but the [kses filters makes it break](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38715).

I would like to remove the kses filters when creating or updating (well, saving) a specific post type; anywhere in the code (thus using filters, I guess).

How could I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Instead of saving it in post_conetnt (I know the pain as I have done it before), save it in the post meta

Comment: Thanks @Buttered_Toast. I ended up doing that, + using the `edit_post_content` filter, which allows me to "fake" the post_content when editing a post.